# How To determine the ResultSet Column type dynamically

Tags: java, resultset

I need to generate an INSERT stmt for all the tables in DB dynamically at runtime. I'm fetching the table contents(data) one by one and determining the column type at runtime while looping thru the ResultSet & ResultSetMetaData in order to add Double Quotes(") for String type and not adding the same for non String types of columns. However with the current logic implemented, it ignores the first record and works perfectly fine for all remaining records in a table. I know why it is working, as while fetching the `rs.getColumnType(int columnIndex)` we need to give column name which starts from 1 index..but not able to build the logic so that it will check the first row also rather then ignoring it at the moment..

Please see below code snippet

```java
if (rs != null) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        sqlString = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            Object obj = rs.getObject(i);

            if (obj == null) {
                sqlString.append("null");
                sqlString.append(",");
            }
            else
            {
                int sqlTypes = rsmd.getColumnType(i);

                switch (sqlTypes) {
                    case Types.VARCHAR:
                        sqlString.append("\"");
                        if (obj != null)
                            sqlString.append(rs.getString(i));

                        sqlString.append("\"");
                        sqlString.append(",");
                        break;
                    case Types.NULL:
                        sqlString.append("null");
                        sqlString.append(",");
                        break;
                    case Types.CHAR:
                        sqlString.append("\"");
                        if (obj != null)
                            sqlString.append(rs.getString(i));

                        sqlString.append("\"");
                        sqlString.append(",");
                        break;
                    case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                        sqlString.append("\"");
                        if (obj != null)
                            sqlString.append(rs.getTimestamp(i));

                        sqlString.append("\"");
                        sqlString.append(",");
                        break;
                    case Types.DOUBLE:
                        if (obj != null)
                            sqlString.append(rs.getDouble(i));

                        sqlString.append(",");
                        break;
                    case Types.INTEGER:
                        if (obj != null)
                            sqlString.append(rs.getInt(i));

                        sqlString.append(",");
                        break;
                    case Types.SMALLINT:
                        if (obj != null)
                            sqlString.append(rs.getInt(i));

                        sqlString.append(",");
                        break;
                    case Types.DECIMAL:
                        if (obj != null)
                            sqlString.append(rs.getBigDecimal(i));

                        sqlString.append(",");
                        break;

                    /*default:
                        if (obj != null)
                            sqlString.append(obj.toString());

                        sqlString.append(",");
                        break;*/
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you iterate over all rows? "while (rs.next())"

You only have to fetch the ResultSetMetaData once! Every row will have exactly the same metadata. You do not need to call "rs.next()"

Comment: Agree, but I need to iterate over all rows because I need to get the data as well to generate a INSERT stmt for that row, hence the rs.next(), not sure if that answers your query

Comment: If I understand you right, than your task is to export the data from a mysql database. There are tools, which can do that far better, than your own programm. 
Please think of the problems, when the data changes while your export is runnning. Particularly when a table references another.
I would search for the right tool to do the export-job.

Comment: This Needs to be generated pro-grammatically via Java code within the application process to implement some requirement, hence this kind of implementation :)

Comment: Just call `rs.getSomething(i-1)`, that's all.

Comment: Doesn't work that way..... Got an exception "Column Index out of range, 0 < 1 "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a do while loop like this:

```
if (rs != null) {
  do{
    sqlString = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        Object obj = rs.getObject(i);

        if (obj == null) {
            sqlString.append("null");
            sqlString.append(",");
        }
        else
        {
            int sqlTypes = rsmd.getColumnType(i);

            switch (sqlTypes) {
                case Types.VARCHAR:
                    sqlString.append("\"");
                    if (obj != null)
                        sqlString.append(rs.getString(i));

                    sqlString.append("\"");
                    sqlString.append(",");
                    break;
                case Types.NULL:
                    sqlString.append("null");
                    sqlString.append(",");
                    break;
                case Types.CHAR:
                    sqlString.append("\"");
                    if (obj != null)
                        sqlString.append(rs.getString(i));

                    sqlString.append("\"");
                    sqlString.append(",");
                    break;
                case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                    sqlString.append("\"");
                    if (obj != null)
                        sqlString.append(rs.getTimestamp(i));

                    sqlString.append("\"");
                    sqlString.append(",");
                    break;
                case Types.DOUBLE:
                    if (obj != null)
                        sqlString.append(rs.getDouble(i));

                    sqlString.append(",");
                    break;
                case Types.INTEGER:
                    if (obj != null)
                        sqlString.append(rs.getInt(i));

                    sqlString.append(",");
                    break;
                case Types.SMALLINT:
                    if (obj != null)
                        sqlString.append(rs.getInt(i));

                    sqlString.append(",");
                    break;
                case Types.DECIMAL:
                    if (obj != null)
                        sqlString.append(rs.getBigDecimal(i));

                    sqlString.append(",");
                    break;

                /*default:
                    if (obj != null)
                        sqlString.append(obj.toString());

                    sqlString.append(",");
                    break;*/
            }
        }while (rs.next());
    }
```

Comment: Nope. It throws up the same error i.e. Column Index out of range, 0 < 1. Basically the issue is loop starts with 1st index as it is required for fetColumnType() and the rs pointer moves to first row, when I do rs.getObject(i). Hope you understand the situation..

Comment: Apologies for above comment, it works perfectly fine. Appreciate!!